# Get photos that contains disparity data in iOS11 from PhotoKit

Tags: ios, swift, photokit

I want to get the user photos that contains disparity data, my first thought was to use the smart album `.smartAlbumDepthEffect` but since `Portrait Mode` photos taken in iOS 10 doesn't have disparity data that won't work. Is there a way to query PhotoKit and specify that I only want receive photos that has the disparity data?